# Java app deploying on heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have troubles with my Procfile, I think. I can`t deploy my app on heroku, always getting this in logs:

> 2016-03-25T12:46:43.601893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 45751 target/*.war`
>   2016-03-25T12:46:46.615217+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
>   2016-03-25T12:46:46.617375+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to access jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
>   2016-03-25T12:46:47.819108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
>   2016-03-25T12:46:47.877603+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

This is my Procfile:
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war

This is my project on [gitHub](https://github.com/ilyach12/Catalog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see webapp-runner.jar in your pom.

Heroku seems not able to find this dependency too.

```
<!--  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner  -->
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                            <version>8.0.24.0</version>
                            <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Now I getting this 

> 2016-03-28T10:57:57.397887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/catalog/get" host=murmuring-shore.herokuapp.com request_id=0a40ddbd-1f49-4b72-a287-22d5a6364540 fwd="myIP" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

Comment: An [H12 error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout) means the request timed-out after 30 seconds. That sounds like the app is running now, but something else is wrong.